# How to insert embedded YouTube player into LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: video, libreoffice, youtube

In PowerPoint one is able to insert a YouTube embedded player by providing the program with a link so that the video can be played from within the actual slide rather than one having to open it in a browser.

But I haven't been able to find such functionality in LibreOffice Impress. Is there such a feature? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22.

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/15336/inserting-you-tube-video-into-pptimpress-presentation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to download a video in order to embed it in a slide in LibreOffice Impress. I recommend downloading an mp4 format video, because YouTube usually provides a big selection of video resolutions for the mp4 format, which will give you control of the size of the finished presentation.

1. Install GStreamer backend for LibreOffice and youtube-dl.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer youtube-dl
   ```
2. Download a video in from YouTube using youtube-dl. The video format should be mp4 or any other video format that is supported by LibreOffice Impress. The resolution of the downloaded video controls the size of the video on the slide. If you want to see a small video box in the slide, then select a low resolution like 426x240 in the youtube-dl options. Selecting a low resolution will also produce a presentation of manageable size.
3. In Impress select *Insert* -> *Movie and Sound...*
4. A new **Insert Movie and Sound** window will open. You can see a list of supported video formats by opening the dropdown list of file types in the bottom right corner of the Insert Movie and Sound window. Browse to a video, select the video and click the *Open* button in the lower right corner to embed the video in a slide.
5. The controls for play, pause and stop will appear in the bottom left corner of the Impress interface. When you start a slide show and navigate to a slide which has a video embedded in it, the video will start playing automatically. When you go to the next slide or stop the slide show, the video will stop playing automatically.